# error: passing ‘const std::unordered_map<char, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I am struggling with understanding why `auto p` in the following code snippet is `const` type, which prevents the query `cnt_w[p.first]`. I understand the error msg `error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::unordered_map<char,intmstd::hash<char>`, because in c++,when the key is not existed in the unordered_map, it will implement insertion. **Could you please enlighten me why `auto p` is const_iterator? or when did my `cnt_t, cnt_w` become const type?** It really confuses me pretty hard.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    unordered_map<char, int> cnt_t, cnt_w;
    string t = "ABCF";
    string s = "ABCF";
    for (auto c: t)
        cnt_t[c] += 1;
    for (auto c: s)
        cnt_w[c] += 1;
    if (all_of(cnt_t.begin(), cnt_t.end(), [cnt_w = &cnt_w](auto p) { return cnt_w[p.first] >= p.second; }))
        cout << "TRUE" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can use `cnt_w.at(p.first)` instead of `cnt_w[p.first]` to avoid the
`error: passing ‘const std::unordered_map<char, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers` as shown below, but `cnt_w.at(p.first)` would cause an error when the key is not existed.

```
int main(void) {
    unordered_map<char, int> cnt_t, cnt_w;
    string t = "ABCF";
    string s = "ABCF";
    for (auto c: t)
        cnt_t[c] += 1;
    for (auto c: s)
        cnt_w[c] += 1;
    if (all_of(cnt_t.begin(), cnt_t.end(), [cnt_w = cnt_w](auto p) { return cnt_w.at(p.first) >= p.second; }))
        cout << "TRUE" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside - see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102). Simply remove it and include `unordered_map`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and `<algorithm>` but I agree

Comment: Good catch, you need `unordered_map` and `algorithm` for `std::all_of()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing wrong in the first case. You should use `[&cnt_w = cnt_w]` or just `[&cnt_w]`. `cnt_w` here is non-const.

What you're doing is getting the address of `cnt_w`

Comment: thank @Nimrod very much. Yes, ````[&cnt_w = cnt_w]```` and  ````[&cnt_w]```` work well. Could you please explain the meaning of ````[&cnt_w = cnt_w]```` and  ````[&cnt_w] ````? Ang why  ````[cnt_w = cnt_w]```` failed? I am teaching my c++ with a background in python. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure. `&` here means `cnt_w` is captured by (non-const) reference, while `[cnt_w = cnt_w]` or `[cnt_w]` means `cnt_w` is captured by copy, which is const. see more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)